# How is Lagrangian mechanics employed to model rigid body motion?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

Whenever I've used Lagrangian mechanics, it's always been in the context of systems of point particles under certain potentials, never dealing with a continuous body. This makes me wonder, how does the formalism tackle something like rigid body motion? I assume you'd have to choose some generalized coordinates with respect to the position of the center of mass and the orientation of the body.

Comment: Are you familiar with Inertia Tensor ? It encapsulates all of the information about the rotation of a rigid body. You define the Kinetic Lagrangian using this. If you are not familiar, I can make a more elaborate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141941 ? Or an introductory book on theoretical mechanics, perhaps?

Comment: This is probably too big of a topic to be effectively answered in this format.  It usually takes up a chapter or two of an upper-level mechanics textbook such as Taylor, Thornton & Marion, or Goldstein.